# How to judge the form of matrix multiplication?(faster ways please)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image: click this to show the picture]

I wonder if it exists a faster way to know it is B=AC OR CA

Answer (score 2):

If $B$ and $A$ are column vectors, then you have $B=CA$ and $B_i=\sum_{k=1}^n C_{ik}A_k$.

If $B$ and $A$ are row vectors, then $B=AC$ and $B_i=\sum_{k=1}^n C_{ki}A_k$.

So this is the latter.

Comment: Much thanks to Gae. S. for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In this question, it is assumed that the first coordinate represents rows and the second columns.

$a^Tc=\left(\begin{matrix}a_1&...&a_n\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}|&&|\\c_1&...&c_n\\|&&|\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}a^Tc_1&...&a^Tc_n\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}a_1c_{11}+...+a_nc_{n1}&...&a_1c_{1n}+...+a_nc_{nn}\end{matrix}\right)$

also $a^Tc=\left(\begin{matrix}a_1&...&a_n\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}-c_1^T-\\...\\-c_n^T-\end{matrix}\right)=a_1c_1^T+...+a_nc_n^T=\left(\begin{matrix}a_1c_{11}+...+a_nc_{n1}&...&a_1c_{1n}+...+a_nc_{nn}\end{matrix}\right)$

On the other hand,

$ca=\left(\begin{matrix}|&&|\\c_1&...&c_n\\|&&|\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}a_1\\...\\a_n\end{matrix}\right)=a_1c_1+....+a_nc_n=\left(\begin{matrix}a_1c_{11}+...+a_nc_{1n}\\...\\a_nc_{n1}+...+a_nc_{nn}\end{matrix}\right)$

$ca=\left(\begin{matrix}-c_1^T-\\...\\-c_n^T-\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}a_1\\...\\a_n\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}c_1^Ta_1\\...\\c_1^Ta_n\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}a_1c_{11}+...+a_nc_{1n}\\...\\a_nc_{n1}+...+a_nc_{nn}\end{matrix}\right)$

Thus I conclude if it is the first coordinate that stays still in each $b_i=\sum _jc_{ij}$ (the second coordinate varies) that $b=ca$, i.e. a is a column vector multiplied from the right. If it is $b_j=\sum_ic_{ij}$ (the first coordinate varies), then $b=a^Tc$, i.e. a is a column vector multiplied from the left.

**The trick is if it is b_i, then b is a column vector. If b_j, then b is a row vector.**

Comment: Much thanks to Stacker for your help!